# Best book for learn principal component analysis

Tags: pca, references

Which book could you recommend for me to study principal component analysis at an intermediate level?

I have studied multivariate statistics, but I want to delve into this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider this book, chapter 8: [Applied Multivariate Statistical Analysis, 6th Edition](https://www.pearson.com/us/higher-education/program/Johnson-Applied-Multivariate-Statistical-Analysis-6th-Edition/PGM274834.html?tab=contents). One of the applications of PCA is to make a (PCA) bi-plot which you can find [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01A64DO4I).

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259596400_Principal_component_analysis_A_beginner's_guide_-_I_Introduction_and_application and Jolliffe's book

Answer (score 0):

A newer book that seems interesting is [Generalized Principal Component Analysis](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-87811-9) by
René Vidal, Yi MaS. S. Sastry.

From the editorial review:

> Introduces fundamental statistical, geometric and algebraic concepts

> Encompasses relevant data clustering and modeling methods in machine learning

> Addresses a general class of unsupervised learning problems

> Generalizes the theory and methods of principal component anaylsis to the cases when the data can be severely contaminated with errors and outliers as well as when the data may contain more than one low-dimensional subspace